# juju openstack bootstrap authentication failed

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud

I installed juju on Ubuntu via snap and follow these steps https://docs.jujucharms.com/2.4/en/help-openstack.

But if I try to run the bootstrap to start the controller I always get an 401 error message - authentication failed

```
# juju bootstrap openstack --debug
22:36:06 INFO  juju.cmd supercommand.go:56 running juju [2.4.0 gc go1.10]
...    
22:36:06 INFO  juju.provider.openstack provider.go:146 opening model "controller"
22:36:06 DEBUG juju.provider.openstack provider.go:805 authentication failed: authentication failed
caused by: requesting token: Unauthorised URL https://horizon.my-os.com:5000/v3/auth/tokens
caused by: request (https://horizon.my-os.com:5000/v3/auth/tokens) returned unexpected status: 401; error info: Failed: 401 error: The request you have made requires authentication.
ERROR authentication failed.
```

I used the autoload function to read credentials from env. The openstack command works fine e.g. openstack port list.

I also could call the endpoint with curl and get an token.

```
# juju show-cloud openstack
defined: local
type: openstack
description: Openstack Cloud
auth-types: [access-key, userpass]
regions:
  RegionOne:
    endpoint: https://horizon.my-os.com:5000/v3
```

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint seems to me wrong. It should be your keystone (identity service in O~S), not your horizon which is only a frontend. 
Try `openstack endpoint list` and check the correct identity endpoint and the try to use that in your configuration.

Let me know if useful.

Comment: same problem also using keystone.  I've opened this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134575/apps-modelling-on-openstack-via-juju